# Why does cryptsetup fail with container 10M in size?

Tags: encryption, luks

I'm trying to create an encrypted volume 10M in size. I know this is possible because I have tombs that are 10M in size. I've run the following commands.

```
fallocate -l 10M container
cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat --progress-frequency 1 container
cryptsetup open --type luks container luksvol1
```

And I get the following error message.

```
Requested offset is beyond real size of device container.
```

But my commands succeed if my container is 20M in size. Why does this fail with 10M? 10M should be plenty large to hold an encrypted luks volume.

Comment: According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814528/cryptsetup-luksformat-error-requested-offset-is-beyond-real-size-of-device-dev) over at Stack Overflow, it's caused by your loopback device.  Try the 2015 suggestion of closing your devices and free your loopback devices.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The original LUKS volume format, now known as LUKS1, used to reserve 2 MiB for the metadata header (cipher parameters, key slots, etc.) leaving you with 8 MiB for the actual data.

But with introduction of LUKS2 which uses a different metadata format, the default data offset is now **16 MiB**. The problem is, `cryptsetup luksFormat` does not actually check whether the device is large enough, it just blindly writes the header.

(In both format versions, the original reason for a large key-slot area is the usage of "anti-forensic striping", i.e. each 32-byte key is spread across multiple sectors. But in addition to that, LUKS2 stores a part of its metadata using JSON instead of packed binary structures, so the metadata area has been grown to account for the new overhead.)

Your options are either to:

- initialize the volume using `luksFormat --type luks1` (which will use a 2 MiB offset);
- or initialize the LUKS volume with different `--luks2-metadata-size` and `--luks2-keyslots-size` values. (Note: I don't know what the minimum safe size is.)

Both LUKS versions use the same ciphers; the main practical advantage of LUKS2 is that it supports the Argon2 KDF while LUKS1 is limited to PBKDF2 only.

Comment: LUKS2 also supports dm-integrity.

Comment: I think a corresponding bug should be filed (at least asking for confirmation to create such an unusable LUKS device).